# VHDL Factorial calculator

Tags: vhdl

I am attempting to create a 16-bit factorial calculator for an unsigned binary number.  In doing so I have created a data path and a state machine that

a.) outputs a final value of 1 if the value input is 0

b.) displays and overflow flag if the input is over 8!

c.) Calculates the value for the factorial if the value input is less then 8 and not zero.

The system seems to fall apart if the value I input is anything over 3 yet still not an overflow.  I think the issue is somewhere in Test3, Update 1, update 2 in my state machine.  Could anyone help explain what is going wrong?

State Machine:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity fact_16_ctrlv2 is
     port(
         go : in STD_LOGIC;
         clk : in STD_LOGIC;
         clr : in STD_LOGIC;
         overflow : in STD_LOGIC;
         numeqcnt : in STD_LOGIC;
         factzero : in STD_LOGIC; 
         flag: out STD_logic;
         xload : out STD_LOGIC;
         cntmux : out STD_LOGIC;
         cntload : out STD_LOGIC;
         factload : out STD_LOGIC;
         factmux : out STD_LOGIC;
         finalload : out STD_LOGIC; 
         finalmuxselect: out STD_logic;  
         decimalpoint: out std_logic
         );
end fact_16_ctrlv2;

--}} End of automatically maintained section

architecture fact_16_ctrlv2 of fact_16_ctrlv2 is 
type state_type is (start, input, test1, test2, test3, update1, update2, update3, done);
signal present_state, next_state: state_type;
begin    

    sreg: process(clk, clr)
    begin
    if clr='1' then 
    present_state <= start;

    elsif clk'event and clk='1' then
        present_state <= next_state;
    end if;
    end process;

    c1: process(present_state, go, overflow, factzero, numeqcnt)
    begin
        case present_state is
            when start =>
            if go = '1' then
                next_state <= input;
            else 
                next_state <= start;
            end if;

            when input =>
            next_state <= test1;

            when test1 =>
            if factzero= '1' then
                next_state <= done;
            else 
                next_state <= test2;
            end if;

            when test2 =>
            if overflow = '1' then
                next_state <= done;
            else 
                next_state <= update3;
            end if;  

            when update3 =>
            next_state <= test3;

            when test3 =>
            if numeqcnt = '1' then
                next_state <= done;
            else    
                next_state <= update1;
            end if;  


            when update1 =>
            next_state <= update2;

            when update2 =>
            next_state <= test3; 

            when done =>
            next_state <= done;

            when others =>
            null;


            end case;
            end process;

    C2: process(present_state, overflow, numeqcnt, factzero)
    begin        
        xload<= '0'; 
        flag <= '0';
        cntmux <= '0';
        cntload<= '0';
        factload<='0';
        factmux<='0';
        finalload <='0';
        finalmuxselect<='0';
        decimalpoint<='0';

        case present_state is

            when input =>
            xload<='1';
            --cntmux<='1';
            --cntload<='1';

            when test2 => 
            if  overflow ='1' then 
                flag <= '1';
                finalmuxselect<='0';
                finalload<='1';
                factload <='1'; 
                decimalpoint <='1';

            end if; 

            when test1 =>

            if factzero ='1' then
                flag <= '1';
                finalmuxselect <='1';
                finalload <='1';
            end if;

            when update3 =>
               cntmux<='1';
               cntload<='1';  
               factmux<= '1';
               factload<= '1';

            when test3 => 

            if numeqcnt ='1' then
            finalmuxselect<='0';
            --finalload<='1';
            factload <='1'; 
            cntload<='1';
            factmux<='0';
            else 

            end if;     

            when update1 =>

            factmux<='0';
            factload<='1';


            when update2 => 

            cntmux<='0';
            cntload<='1';  
            --factload<='1';


            when done =>
            finalload<='1';
            when others =>
            null;

        end case;
        end process;

    end fact_16_ctrlv2;
```

Data Path

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity fact_16_dp is
    port(    
         clr : in STD_LOGIC;
         clk : in STD_LOGIC;
         X : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
         overflow : out STD_LOGIC;
         finalfact : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);     
         cntload, cntmult, factload, factmult, xload, finalload :in Std_logic;  
         equalone, numcnt : out Std_logic;  
         finalmuxselect, flagin: in STD_logic
         );
end fact_16_dp;

--}} End of automatically maintained section

architecture fact_16_dp of fact_16_dp is  
    -- Component declaration of the "mult16b(mult16b)" unit defined in
    -- file: "./../src/multiplier.vhd"
    component mult16b
    port(
        a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        p : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0));
    end component;
    for all: mult16b use entity work.mult16b(mult16b);

        -- Component declaration of the "comp(comp)" unit defined in
    -- file: "./../src/comparitor.vhd"
    component comp
    generic(
        N : INTEGER := 8);
    port(
        x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        gt : out STD_LOGIC;
        eq : out STD_LOGIC;
        lt : out STD_LOGIC);
    end component;
    for all: comp use entity work.comp(comp);
        -- Component declaration of the "adder(adder)" unit defined in
    -- file: "./../src/adder.vhd"
    component adder
    generic(
        N : INTEGER := 8);
    port(
        a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0));
    end component;
    for all: adder use entity work.adder(adder);

        -- Component declaration of the "reg(reg)" unit defined in
    -- file: "./../src/reg.vhd"
    component reg
    generic(
        N : INTEGER := 8);
    port(
        load : in STD_LOGIC;
        clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        clr : in STD_LOGIC;
        d : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0));
    end component;
    for all: reg use entity work.reg(reg);
        -- Component declaration of the "mux2g(mux2g)" unit defined in
    -- file: "./../src/mux21.vhd"
    component mux2g
    generic(
        N : INTEGER);
    port(
        a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        s : in STD_LOGIC;
        y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0));
    end component;
    for all: mux2g use entity work.mux2g(mux2g);

        -- Component declaration of the "mux4g(mux4g)" unit defined in
    -- file: "./../src/mux4to1.vhd"
    component mux4g
    generic(
        N : INTEGER);
    port(
        a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        c : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        s : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
        y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0));
    end component;
    for all: mux4g use entity work.mux4g(mux4g);




--signal cntload, cntmult, numcnt, factload, factmult, xload, numload, equalone, finalload :Std_logic;
signal  adderout, cntregout, cntregin, x2 :Std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal xin, factregin, factregout, overin, factmout, checkzero, numregout, flag, finalmuxout, cntregoutb :Std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

begin 
    x2 <= x;
    xin <= "000000000000" & x2;  --Change 4 bit number input into a 16 bit number
    cntregoutb <= "000000000000" & cntregout; --change count from 4 bit value to a 16 bit value 
    flag <= "000000000000000" & flagin;
    cntreg : reg --4-bit counter register
    generic map(
        N => 4
    )
    port map(
        load => cntload,
        clk => clk,
        clr => clr,
        d => cntregin,  --not in drawing
        q => cntregout
    );  

    factreg : reg  --16-bit fact register
    generic map(
        N => 16
    )
    port map(
        load => factload,
        clk => clk,
        clr => clr,
        d => factregin,
        q => factregout
    );

    --numreg : reg --16-bit num register
    --generic map(
        --N => 16
    --)
    --port map(
        --load => numload,
        --clk => clk,
        --clr => clr,
        --d => xin,
        --q => numregout
    --);    

    xreg : reg  --4-bit initial x vlaue register
    generic map(
        N => 4
    )
    port map(
        load => xload,
        clk => clk,
        clr => clr,
        d => x,   --x(3:0)
        q => x2
    );     

    finalreg : reg   --16-bit final fact register
    generic map(
        N => 16
    )
    port map(
        load => finalload,
        clk => clk,
        clr => clr,
        d => finalmuxout,
        q => finalfact
    );  

     cntmux : mux2g --4-bit cnt mux
    generic map(
        N => 4
    )
    port map(
        b => "0001",  --initial value set
        a => adderout, --value after initial run through
        s => cntmult,
        y => cntregin  --cntregin not in drawing
    );     

    factmux : mux2g  --16-bit fact mux
    generic map(
        N => 16
    )
    port map(
        b => "0000000000000001", --initial value set
        a => factmout,  --value after initial run through
        s => factmult,
        y => factregin
    );  

    add1 : adder  --Increment counter 4-bit
    generic map(
        N => 4
    )
    port map(
        a => cntregout, --add 1
        b => "0001", --1
        y => adderout --out of the adder
    );  

    multiplier : mult16b  --multiply cnt and fact 16-bit
    port map(
        a => factregout,
        b => cntregoutb,  --cnt plus 12 zeros to 16-bit
        p => factmout --Multiplier out
    );   

    greater8 : comp --16-bit check x overflow if greater then 8
    generic map(
        N => 16
    )
    port map(
        x => xin,  --check value to 8
        y => "0000000000001000",
        gt => overflow  --send overflow flag
        --eq => eq,
        --lt => lt
    );   

    check0 : comp  --16-bit check x not equal to zero
    generic map(
        N => 16
    )
    port map(
        x => xin,
        y => "0000000000000000",
        --gt => gt,
        eq => equalone
        --lt => lt
    );   

    numeqcnt : comp  --16-bit check if num equals cnt 
    generic map(
        N => 16
    )
    port map(
        x => xin,
        y => cntregoutb,  --need 16 bit
        --gt => gt,
        eq => numcnt --not in drawing
        --lt => lt
    );       

    finalmux: mux2g
    generic map(
        N => 16
    )
    port map(
        a => factregout,
        b => flag,
        s => finalmuxselect,
        y => finalmuxout
    );


end fact_16_dp;
```

Connected together

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Title       : fact_16
-- Design      : lab4
-- Author      : 
-- Company     : 
--
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- File        : c:\My_Designs\lab4\lab4\src\fact_16.vhd
-- Generated   : Tue Oct 14 16:40:38 2014
-- From        : interface description file
-- By          : Itf2Vhdl ver. 1.22
--
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Description : 
--
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--{{ Section below this comment is automatically maintained
--   and may be overwritten
--{entity {fact_16} architecture {fact_16}}

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity fact_16 is
     port(
         go : in STD_LOGIC;
         clk : in STD_LOGIC;
         clr : in STD_LOGIC;
         x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
         overflowB : out STD_LOGIC;
         factout : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)
         );
end fact_16;

 architecture fact_16 of fact_16 is 

    -- Component declaration of the "fact_16_dp(fact_16_dp)" unit defined in
    -- file: "./../src/fact_16_dp.vhd"
    component fact_16_dp
    port(
        clr : in STD_LOGIC;
        clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        X : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
        overflow : out STD_LOGIC;
        finalfact : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        cntload : in STD_LOGIC;
        cntmult : in STD_LOGIC;
        factload : in STD_LOGIC;
        factmult : in STD_LOGIC;
        xload : in STD_LOGIC;
        finalload : in STD_LOGIC;
        equalone : out STD_LOGIC;
        numcnt : out STD_LOGIC;
        finalmuxselect : in STD_LOGIC;
        flagin : in STD_LOGIC);
    end component;
    for all: fact_16_dp use entity work.fact_16_dp(fact_16_dp);

    -- Component declaration of the "fact_16_ctrlv2(fact_16_ctrlv2)" unit defined in
    -- file: "./../src/fact_16_ctrlv2.vhd"
    component fact_16_ctrlv2
    port(
        go : in STD_LOGIC;
        clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        clr : in STD_LOGIC;
        overflow : in STD_LOGIC;
        numeqcnt : in STD_LOGIC;
        factzero : in STD_LOGIC;
        flag : out STD_LOGIC;
        xload : out STD_LOGIC;
        cntmux : out STD_LOGIC;
        cntload : out STD_LOGIC;
        factload : out STD_LOGIC;
        factmux : out STD_LOGIC;
        finalload : out STD_LOGIC;
        finalmuxselect : out STD_LOGIC;
        decimalpoint : out STD_LOGIC);
    end component;
    for all: fact_16_ctrlv2 use entity work.fact_16_ctrlv2(fact_16_ctrlv2);


signal overflow, numeqcnt, factzero, xload, cntmux, cntload, factload, flag, factmux, numload, finalload: STD_logic;    
signal finalmuxselect: std_logic;

begin      

Dpath : fact_16_dp
    port map(
        clr => clr,
        clk => clk,
        X => X,
        overflow => overflow,
        finalfact => factout,
        cntload => cntload,
        cntmult => cntmux,
        factload => factload,
        factmult => factmux,
        xload => xload,
        finalload => finalload,
        equalone => factzero,
        numcnt => numeqcnt,
        finalmuxselect => finalmuxselect,
        flagin => flag
    );

Cunit : fact_16_ctrlv2
    port map(
        go => go,
        clk => clk,
        clr => clr,
        overflow => overflow,
        numeqcnt => numeqcnt,
        factzero => factzero,
        flag => flag,
        xload => xload,
        cntmux => cntmux,
        cntload => cntload,
        factload => factload,
        factmux => factmux,
        finalload => finalload,
        finalmuxselect => finalmuxselect,
        decimalpoint => overflowB
    );

end fact_16;
```

Comment: Since there are so few possible results why not just use a lookup table ?

Comment: the requirements are to use a state machine / data path

Comment: What is going wrong is that you have managed to bury yourself in immense complexity, completely unwarranted by the problem. As you suspect the state machine I would make two suggestions : 1) scrap it and rewrite in single-process form. 2) Write a testbench and simulate the state machine in isolation, until it does exactly what you expect.